# Selecionar um valor dependendo da metragem escolhida

Tags: php, sql

Preciso retornar o valor de um produto de acordo com a metragem escolhida, este valor esta gravado em uma tabela desta forma

```
de_mt | ate_mt | valor_mt
--------------------------
  1   |   5    |  15.00
  6   |   8    |  16.00
  9   |   15   |  16.50
```

Estes valores são inseridos pelo admin, e o usuário só coloca a metragem.

Digamos que o usuário insira **7** o sistema teria que trazer o valor de **16.00**

Já tentei (**Sei que não teria logica, mas foi so uma tentativa**)

```
SELECT * FROM valor_metro WHERE de_mt >= '7' AND  ate_mt <= '7'
```

E tambem com **BETWEEN**
Mas não deu em nada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que invertendo levemente sua lógica funcione da forma como está esperando:

```
SELECT * FROM valor_metro WHERE 7 BETWEEN de_mt AND ate_mt
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4e367a/1/0

Comment: Obrigado, realmente estava tentando da forma errada, obrigado pela ajuda